# Django friend post model storage to create feed

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a custom user model extended with a one to one relationship to a Profile model, I also have a Post model. I want to create an attribute inside of Profile to store Posts of the user's friends to make a recent updates feed. However, I am struggling with what attribute or type of data storage to use (IDK what to call it). Can anyone help? The line of code relevant is bolded in the code below

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='Default.png', upload_to='Profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    relationship = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)
    **feed_posts = ArrayField(blank=True, default=list)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use many to many relationship with posts to which will store posts IDs of users friends